# Help solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i(ap+b\sqrt{k^2-p^2})}}{\sqrt{k^2-p^2}}dp$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the following intergral using complex function theory:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i(ap+b\sqrt{k^2-p^2})}}{\sqrt{k^2-p^2}}dp
\end{equation}

Is there someone that has a hint for me?

Kind Regards,
Micheal